# How to return a value (by setting a variable) in dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)

DECLARE @countnumber int = 0

SET @sqlCommand = 'Set @countnumber = (SELECT count(*) from dsnv)'

EXEC (@sqlCommand)

print @countnumber ;
```

But i get error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use sp_executesql with output parameter

```
DECLARE @countnumber int = 0

SET @sqlCommand = 'Set @countnumber = (SELECT count(*) from dsnv)'

exec sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@countnumber int OUTPUT', @countnumber OUTPUT

print @countnumber ;
```